# TestNG:Exception in thread "main" com.beust.jcommander.ParameterException: Unknown option: -protocol

Tags: testng, testng-eclipse

On running the testng.xml, I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.beust.jcommander.ParameterException: Unknown option: -protocol
    at com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.parseValues(JCommander.java:742)
    at com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.parse(JCommander.java:282)
    at com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.parse(JCommander.java:265)
    at com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.<init>(JCommander.java:210)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:161)
```

No errors are there in the actual selenium classes.

Comment: How do you run the suite ? With Eclipse ?

Comment: Which version of Eclipse, TestNG and testng plugin are you using ?

Comment: Yes, with Eclipse.Eclipse Neon.1a

Comment: testng-6.9.13.6.jar and TestNG plug-in for Eclipse.

Comment: I created the issue: https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse/issues/297

Comment: @Arnrudh, could navigate to "Window -> Show View -> Others -> Error Log", locate to the entry of '[TestNGLaunchConfigurationDelegate] Launching:', copy and paste the content here? since i'd like to know the classpath

Comment: eclipse.buildId=4.6.1.M20160907-1200
java.version=1.8.0_40
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_IN
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.productorg.testng.eclipse
Info
Fri Oct 28 09:09:02 IST 2016
[TestNGLaunchConfigurationDelegate] Launching:

Comment: Classpath: C:\Program Files\eclipse-jee-neon-1a-win32-x86_64\eclipse\plugins\org.testng.eclipse_6.9.13.201609291640\lib\testng-remote.jar C:\Users\anirudhsn\workspace\Arrhythmia\target\classes C:\Program Files\eclipse-jee-neon-1a-win32-x86_64\eclipse\plugins\org.junit_4.12.0.v201504281640\junit.jar C:\Program Files\eclipse-jee-neon-1a-win32-x86_64\eclipse\plugins\org.hamcrest.core_1.3.0.v201303031735.jar C:\Users\anirudhsn\Downloads\selenium-java-3.0.0-beta3 (1)\lib\cglib-nodep-3.2.4.jar C:\Users\anirudhsn\Downloads\selenium-java-3.0.0-beta3 (1)\lib\commons-codec-1.10.jar

Comment: @ XuQing Tan, I am unable to paste all content of classpath here due to space limitation.

Comment: @Anirudh, somehow the older version of RemoteTestNG inside your fat selenium jar was loaded first, though I saw the new testng-remote.jar is at the front of classpath; Could you share a sample project to reproduce the issue. let's track it on github ticket: https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse/issues/297, thanks

Comment: @Anirudh, I just downloaded the latest selenium-java 3.0.1, I don't see testng was embedded in any fat jar, so, could you try with this version? and also please confirm there is only one TestNG (to be more specific RemoteTestNG) on your classpath.

Comment: @XuQing, I tried with selenium-java 3.0.1 also. But,still I am getting the same error.

Comment: could you add '-verbose:class' to JVM arguments when launch the testng process in Eclipse. on the stdout, it would print something like this: [Loaded org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG from file:/Users/nick/workspace/myproject/testng-eclipse/testng-eclipse-plugin/lib/testng-remote.jar]
[Loaded org.testng.TestNGException from file:/Users/nick/.m2/repository/org/testng/testng/6.9.10/testng-6.9.10.jar]
[Loaded com.beust.jcommander.ParameterException from file:/Users/nick/.m2/repository/com/beust/jcommander/1.48/jcommander-1.48.jar]

Comment: [Loaded java.lang.Shutdown from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.Shutdown$Lock from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\lib\rt.jar]
Exception in thread "main" com.beust.jcommander.ParameterException: Unknown option: -protocol

Comment: could you locate to line "Loaded org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG", need to know where loaded RemoteTestNG class. and please paste the output onto ticket: https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse/issues/297, stack overflow comment is not a good place for tracking this.

Comment: @ XuQing Tan, Issue is resolved. I just removed the RemoteTestNG loaded under file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_40/jre/lib/ext/testng-6.9.6.jar. Thanks for your support.

Comment: I have the same issue on eclipse Version: 2019-12 (4.14.0), testng-7.0.0, testNG plugin 7.0.0. In my case, I don't have any testng under my jdk installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is resolved now. The problem was occurred by the RemoteTestNG loading. So I just removed the C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_40/jre/lib/ext/testng-6.9.6.jar. I am able to run the testng.xml without any error message. Thanks @XuQing Tan for your valuable comments.